# Is it possible to place something in front of iframe?

Tags: html, css

I'm embedding YouTube videos on the page and they appear over drop down menus, over lightbox, etc. I'd rather not use the old YouTube embed code but stupid iframe is obnoxiously putting itself over every other element on the page. Is it possible to make it learn its place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can float both the iframe and whatever you want on top of it inside of a container.

Then, on the items you want on top, just set a negative top margin.

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wXvA/) to show what I mean.

You can also use absolute positioning on the items you want in front, but that typically results in other issues with the site.

## update

It appears you are trying to go against regular HTML flow.  Things that come first in the HTML are generally "under" or before things that come after.

However, you can take an element out of the regular flow of HTML rendering and position it absolutely.

I've [updated the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wXvA/20/) to show how this is done.  Be warned, absolute position could bring other issues into your site design.

Comment: thanks, but the problem is #over comes before iframe on the page, like this http://jsfiddle.net/6wXvA/11/

Comment: Why can't you change the order? :(  What you're trying to do is not uncommon, but tends to go against how HTML is designed.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Well I have a product with images that open using colorbox (like lightbox) and below those images I have YouTube clips of the product. When I click on images, colorbox opens but the YouTube clips are in front of the opened image. All colorbox elements have position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; so it should be in front of the iframe, right?

Comment: I'll fix it somehow using absolute positioning. Thanks.

Comment: @A-OK, just set `iframe` to `position:relative` and `z-index:1`. This will fix your issues without having any side-effects.

Comment: @Gaby works in Firefox and Opera, doesn't work in MSIE, Safari and Google Chrome

Answer (score 5):

**final update**

Adding `?wmode=transparent` at the end of the iframe url or `&amp;wmode=transparent` if there are other params passed as well, seems to fix the issue for all browsers.

---

***original answer***

Use `z-index` combined with positioning (*relative or absolute*)

example with dropdown over a youtube video (*new code*) at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/BS4Ww/3/

---

***update***

*added `div` over `iframe` as well as i misunderstood the dropdown*

Comment: <select> is over/in front of iframe in any case.

Comment: @A-OK, posted solution for all browsers, although it involves altering the url.

Comment: hi! i use this approach and it works OK! BTW, here is an interesting explanation why it works this way http://starikovs.com/2012/10/27/position-html-elm-over-youtube/

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the z-index on the frame.

[z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: downvoted because a simple test on jsfiddle.net or a similar site would show that this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `margin-top:12px;` or something inside your  tag.

Comment: Sorry, I mean OVER like in front, I'll change the title.

Comment: are you placing youtube inside ifram

Comment: yeah, now YouTube uses iframe for embedding, it's nice and short except iframe overlaps any other element on the page

Comment: i think you can apply css for iframe like<iframe style="margin-top12px;">

Answer (score 0):

If you put the iFrame in a div, and set a z-index on the div, this should work.
I do this all the time at work.

Answer (score 0):

for one project I needed similar thing. I intended to display iframe content but not allow user to follow its links. Instead I wanted to point user to another url.
Here is my solution. To work in IE is important to set some background color for over element.

```
 #over{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color:white; /* for unknow reason is color important for IE*/
        opacity:0;
        filter:alpha(opacity=0);    
    }

    iframe{
        width: 100%;
        height: 550px;
    }

    <div>
        <div id="over" onclick="parent.location='....'"></div>
        <iframe src="...">You don't have iframe support, unfortunately</iframe>         
   </div>
```