# How to add a button on the embedded youtube video?

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

I want to add a button on the embedded youtube video on my website. So that a user can easily download that video. Now I just need to display a button on youtube video surface ,so that a user can click the button and do some job (about the video). Button will be like this:
[Click Here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGLiz.png)

with simple html or javascript. Thank You.

Comment: Ofcourse on my own page . I have a page with an embedded youtube video. Now I want to show a button over the youtube video screen. So that  a user can click the button and do some job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a button on top of your iframe is the simple part of the solution, and you will likely find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075270/is-it-possible-to-place-something-in-front-of-iframe) solution helpful. to match the styling, I'd recommend a site like http://css3buttongenerator.com/

As for the second part of this question, it is more advanced to write javascript to download a video, and if you'd like to avoid that, a simpler solution would be to redirect a user to a site like [this](http://www.clipconverter.cc/). you could even go through the steps of downloading the video, and get the final link the site provides when it is ready to download.